# Pictures uploaded from phone to PC show in Shotwell, but I can't find them in my home folder

Tags: shotwell, photo-management

I downloaded pictures from my phone to my computer.

All the pictures are now on Shotwell photo manger, but how do I get them so I can see them from my home folder? I tried right clicking to move them into my home folder but it doesn’t work.

Comment: This is covered in the official Shotwell FAQ. http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/shotwell/wiki/ShotwellFAQ

Answer (score 0):

Typically shotwell saves your photos to /home/[username]/Pictures, take a look on there.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you Right-Click on an image? Does a menu popup? If so you should see **Move To** and **Copy To** on that menu.

Unless you have swapped the left/Right mouse buttons if you are Southpaw, **Left-Click drag** items to move them. Right-Click drag sounds like a Windows thing.